# Carrierwave Fog (S3) Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I am struggling with this setup and have read through Carrierwave docs and still and pulling hair. 
I'm getting an error when I try to start the server even in dev mode.

> Exiting
>   /Users/my-machine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/carrierwave-0.7.1/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:73:in
>   `eval': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)

Here is my setup.

**config/initializers/carrierwave.rb**

```
S3_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'amazon_s3.yml'))[Rails.env]

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage              = :s3
  config.s3_access_policy     = :public_read
  config.s3_access_key_id     = S3_CONFIG['access_key_id']
  config.s3_secret_access_key = S3_CONFIG['secret_access_key']
  config.s3_bucket            = S3_CONFIG['bucket']
  config.s3_region           = 'us-east-1'
end
```

**config/amazon_s3.yml**

```
development:
  access_key_id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  secret_access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  bucket: dev-bucket

test:
  access_key_id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  secret_access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  bucket: test-bucket

production:
  access_key_id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  secret_access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  bucket: prod-bucket
```

**app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb**

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  #storage :file
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # fix for Heroku, unfortunately, it disables caching, 
  # see: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Make-Carrierwave-work-on-Heroku
  def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you establishing your S3_CONFIG environment variables in your development environment? Seems as thou they're missing.

Comment: Hi Chris where would I set those or go about that. Thanks

Comment: Here's a reasonable way to handle it - http://tammersaleh.com/posts/managing-heroku-environment-variables-for-local-development